# How to replace the pattern in string with other string using react and regular expression?

Tags: regex, reactjs

Hi i want to replace string in square brackets with span element.

what i am trying to do?
consider string "i am [2@"some user"] more text"

from the above string i want to extract "some user" and form a string like below,

"i am `<strong>some user<strong>` more text"

so to do that i am using below snippet,

```
stringreplace(/\[(\d+)@(\w+\s+\w+)]/g, '<strong>$2</strong>');
```

but this will put strong as string...

is there some other way to do this? could someone help me solve this. thanks.

Comment: you can use `dangerouslySetInnerHtml` property on an html element

Comment: Your regex doesn't extract the "some user"

Comment: hmm it is actually giving me the "some user".

Comment: thanks i dont want to use dangerouslysetinnerhtml. is it possible to loop through matches and push them to an array with strong element in it. could some one tell me how to do it.

Comment: Do you really have double quotes arround `some user`?

Comment: no double quotes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your question on the comment. Yes you can do it without using `dangerouslySetInnerHtml`, you will have to split the string first, then add the value where you need and render the array.

given

```js
const str = 'i am [123231@some user] more text [32@another user]' // the actual text
const splitReg = /\[\d+@(\w+\s+\w+)]/g // Regex used to split the string
const nameReg = /\[(\d+)@(?<name>\w+\s+\w+)]/g // Regex used to extract the user name
```

you can do something in the lines of

```
  let userNames = [] // array to store all names
  let executedRegexp = nameReg.exec(str)
  while (executedRegexp) {
    executedRegexp  && userNames.push(executedRegexp.groups.name)
    executedRegexp = nameReg.exec(str)
  }
  const replaceStrong = str.split(splitReg).map(v => {
    // If item in array exists in usernames, return a react component
    if (userNames.indexOf(v) >= 0) return <strong>{v}</strong> 
    return v
  })
```

finally you can render the `replaceStrong` value as is

```
const Text = () => <span>{replaceStrong}</span>
```

Comment: thanks .str.split(reg).map where is this reg coming from

Comment: thanks this works perfect for this string 'i am [2@some user] more text' but doesnt work for multiple patterns say this string 'i am [23@another user] some more'. how can i do it.

Comment: Just replaced the `2@` in `splitReg` with `\d+`, should be working now

Comment: thanks. hmm i did that but still the same. actually executedRegexp.groups.name contains only "some user" doesnt contain "another user"

Comment: Can you paste the full string you are matching it against?

Comment: 'i am [123231@some user] more text [32@another user]'

Comment: Glad to help :)